# Can anyone help me solving this error? It says "IDE Internal Error" on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I closed some project the error message appeared on the button side on a window like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHdVg.png)

And that the stacktrace.txt appeared and shows messages like this:

```
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException  at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromiseKt.<clinit>(AsyncPromise.kt:12)     
at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromise.cancel(AsyncPromise.kt:61)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.cancel(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:237)
at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromise.cancel(AsyncPromise.kt:64)    
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.submitOrScheduleCoalesced(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:330)     
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl.submit(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:186)
at com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationsImpl.updateEditors(EditorNotificationsImpl.java:158)
at com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationsImpl.lambda$updateNotifications$0(EditorNotificationsImpl.java:136)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2319)     
at com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationsImpl.updateNotifications(EditorNotificationsImpl.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.AsyncEditorLoader.loadingFinished(AsyncEditorLoader.java:177)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.AsyncEditorLoader.lambda$scheduleLoading$2(AsyncEditorLoader.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.lambda$safeTransferToEdt$6(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:525)    
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:310)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:80)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:128)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:184)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)    
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:847)    
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)     
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:496)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can anyone help me fix this? I run Android Studio 4.1.3

Comment: `Can anyone help me fix this?` what problem is this giving you ? if the IDE failed, you can probably just restart it or it might even work normally still, so are you saying you're completely unable to use it ?

Comment: Stack Overflow shows a preview of your post before you submit. Please look at it and check it. It should be obvious that all that stuff on a single line is unreadable. I shouldn't have to fix it for you.